# LINQ Join NVARCHAR with VARCHAR

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, join, casting

I am trying to join two columns but one is `Varchar` and the other in `NVarchar`

My LINQ code:

```
private BrattleHubEntities officeInfo = new BrattleHubEntities();
private BrattlecubesEntities empInfo = new BrattlecubesEntities();

var employeeOfficeInfo = from t1 in officeInfo.DimOffices
                                     join t2 in empInfo on t1.OfficeCode equals t2.EmployeeOffice
                                     select new { t1.OfficeCode, t1.MainPhone, t1.MainFax }
```

This gives the error message:

> The type of one of the expressions in the Join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

From researching I understand that this is because `empInfo.EmployeeOffice` is a `NVarchar(30)` while `officeInfo.OfficeCode` is `Varchar(20)`

> How do I cast these strings to perform the Join?

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**
I am receiving the same error even with the following code

```
var employeeOfficeInfo = from t1 in officeInfo.DimOffices
                                     join t2 in empInfo on 1 equals 1
                                     select new { t1.OfficeCode, t1.MainPhone, t1.MainFax }
```

Comment: What are the types of `OfficeCode` and `EmployeeOffice`?

Comment: Hi Chris, OfficeCode is `Varchar(20)` and EmployeeOffice is `NVarchar(30)` in the SQL db

Comment: Yes, that's in the question. What are they in the code? I suspect they aren't both strings...

Comment: Could you tell me how to check this?  By looking at the Data Models created when I added the database connection, the `get ; set; ` for both items are expecting a string i.e. `public string EmployeeOffice { get; set; }` can be found in my `DimEmployee.cs` Model (i'm using MVC).

Comment: Additionally, neither is `Nullable` in the Model

Comment: That should do the trick. In visual studio you should also just be able to hover your mouse over the `OfficeCode` bit of `t1.OfficeCode` and it will tell you the type. Sounds like they are both strings though which makes me go back to being confused as to what the cause is... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this, I'm sorry, I excluded the code which was the culprit.

**Original code (complete)**

```
private BrattleHubEntities officeInfo = new BrattleHubEntities();
private BrattlecubesEntities empInfo = new BrattlecubesEntities();

        // GET: DimOffices
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            string currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            string currentUserLogin = currentUser.Substring(10);
            var employee = from e in empInfo.DimEmployees//Method 1 to pull current user
                           select e;
            employee = employee.Where(e => e.UserLogin.Contains(currentUser) && e.EmployeeOffice.Contains("BOS"));

            var employeeOfficeInfo = from t1 in officeInfo.DimOffices
                                     join t2 in empInfo on t1.OfficeCode equals t2.EmployeeOffice
                                     select new { t1.OfficeCode, t1.MainPhone, t1.MainFax };

            return View(employeeOfficeInfo);
        }
```

**Functioning code**

```
private BrattleHubEntities officeInfo = new BrattleHubEntities();
private BrattlecubesEntities empInfo = new BrattlecubesEntities();

        // GET: DimOffices
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            string currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            string currentUserLogin = currentUser.Substring(10);
            var employee = from e in empInfo.DimEmployees//Method 1 to pull current user
                           select e;
            employee = employee.Where(e => e.UserLogin.Contains(currentUser));

            var employeeOfficeInfo = from t1 in officeInfo.DimOffices
                                     join t2 in employee on t1.OfficeCode equals t2.EmployeeOffice
                                     select new { t1.OfficeCode, t1.MainPhone, t1.MainFax };

            return View(employeeOfficeInfo);
        }
```

> The issue was that I was generating a data set on EmpInfo already and had renamed it. If I comment out the var employee logic, I get the issue which I posted about, I'm not sure why the LINQ select was needed on EmpInfo

Answer (score 0):

You could use anon objects returned from nested linq queries to explicitly cast the value of both types in the subquery and then join the result of the two subqueries to return the object you want. The probablem is not technically a sql server one, it is a .NET one. LINQ doesn't know how to join those two data types of the mapped objects together. So you need to explicitly tell link how the two types are related. Alternatively, you could just use tsql to do this query and convert the varchar to an nvarchar. `JOIN t2 ON (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), t1.OfficeCode, 0) = t2.EmployeeOffice)`